# VBA to send email after cell filled in with "Complete"

Tags: vba

Trying to set up a small task tracking workbook that will email our team once a cell gets filled in with "complete" (we use outlook). This is the code I have come up with so far, but I'm having trouble getting it to work

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim varActCell As Variant
Set varActCell = Range(ActiveCell).Offset(rowoffset:=0, columnoffset:=-1)

If Target.Column = 5 And InStr(varActCell, "Complete") Then MsgBox "Success"
call: Emailsub

End Sub
```

I attached a link to a similar thread with the email sub I'll use, but I'm having trouble activating it.

[Can Excel send an email to different users based cell value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19770110/can-excel-send-an-email-to-different-users-based-cell-value)

Answer (score 0):

you must omit those "`:`" between Call and `Emailsub`so that you have to write

```
Call Emailsub
```

but you can also simply type

```
Emailsub
```

finally should your Emailsub be as the `sendMail` of the link you provided then you're also missing passing arguments to your sub like, for instance:

```
sendMail strTo, strSubject, strBodyText 'where the arguments must all be of `String` type
```

while there also are two more `Optional` arguments, which means you can choose to omit whichever of them, like:

```
Emailsub strTo, strSubject, strBodyText, strCC, oAttachments

Emailsub strTo, strSubject, strBodyText, strCC

Emailsub strTo, strSubject, strBodyText, , oAttachments
```

if passed, these last two arguments are expected to be of `String` type and of `Collection` type.

But being `Optional` the Sub can work without you passing any value for them and thus assuming `default` values which are, respectively, a null string ("") and a void Collection

---

Edited to add a usage example
For example you may code like this:

```
strTo = "John@provider.com"
strSubject = "hoping it works"
strBodyText = "this is my very first attempt at using VBA and Outlook"
Emailsub strTo, strSubject, strBodyText
```

Comment: even when i remove the colon, I still get an error (i also cant step through for some reason). Also, to pass the values through, would it be something like: Set strTo = "xxxx@gmail.com"  ?

Comment: See edited answer for an example of how to initialize arguments for subsequent use of Emailsub. As for your impossibility of stepping through your code you'd better post you entire code

Comment: @chs: did you get through it?